# combine proc sql step in proc report to create report in excel

Tags: sas

```
ods html file = "Y:/cars/cars.xls";

proc sql;
title "Cars";
select
make,model,type,origin,drivetrain
from sashelp.class
where engine size gt 3;
quit;
```

Suppose after run above query in SAS I will get output in excel format.
So, how it is possible to get same ouput via proc report step?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't get much output from that since there aren't any cars in sashelp.class.

The basic proc report step will look something like:

```
title "Cars";
proc report data=sashelp.cars nowd;
where enginesize gt 3;
columns make model type origin drivetrain;
run;
```

I wouldn't use PROC REPORT though just to do this - the point of PROC REPORT is all of the other features you can use, between the formatting options, the summarization options, etc.